# Streamreader and StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-overflow

I have a `StackOverflowException` when assigning my `StreamReader` to read a file, I don't know why this is occurring :(

Here is the exception details:

```
$exception  {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}   System.StackOverflowException
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2147023895 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        Message "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown." string
        Source  null    string
        StackTrace  null    string
        TargetSite  null    System.Reflection.MethodBase
+       Static members      
+       Non-Public members
```

Here is the code:

```
class Compile_Import
{
    public static string getargs = null;
    private static StreamReader sr;
    public static void CompileAndRun(FileInfo importInfo, string args)
    {
        getargs = args;
        if(importInfo.Extension == ".cbe" && importInfo.Exists)
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(importInfo.FullName); //Where my problem occurs.
            string curlinecont = null;
            while((curlinecont = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string RawToken = 
             Parser.Parse.ParseLineIntoToken(Run.Stats.CurrentLineContents);
                Token_Management.Process_Token.ActOnToken(RawToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: How big is the file which you are trying to read?

Comment: The file is probably just a few lines actually, its just around 1kb

Comment: Can you post importInfo.FullName property code? May be its going into some kind of recurssion?

Comment: We need to see the `ParseLineIntoToken()` and `ActOnToken()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is related to your issue, but using a static variable for `StreamReader` means that if 2 threads call `CompileAndRun` at the same time, there will likely be problems.

Also, `StreamReader` imlements `IDisposable`, so you should call `Dispose` on it or use a `using` block like this:

```
class Compile_Import
{
    public static string getargs = null;
    public static void CompileAndRun(FileInfo importInfo, string args)
    {
        getargs = args;
        if(importInfo.Extension == ".cbe" && importInfo.Exists)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(importInfo.FullName)) //Where my problem occurs.
            {
                string curlinecont = null;
                while((curlinecont = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string RawToken = 
                 Parser.Parse.ParseLineIntoToken(Run.Stats.CurrentLineContents);
                    Token_Management.Process_Token.ActOnToken(RawToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition, shouldn't this line:

```
string RawToken = 
    Parser.Parse.ParseLineIntoToken(Run.Stats.CurrentLineContents);
```

be:

```
string RawToken = 
    Parser.Parse.ParseLineIntoToken(curlinecont);
```

? Otherwise, you are not using the line that is read from the file anywhere, so it makes reading the file pointless.

Comment: I cant believe i never spotted this, thankyou! (yes it worked.)